# Lollipop: heads-up notification is canceled when clicked

Tags: android

I have searched for quite some time now, but I'm unable to find an answer. My app displays a notification with `Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH` which causes it to be displayed as a heads-up notification on Lollipop.

The problem is that when clicking the notification itself (i.e. launching its `contentIntent`) the notification is automatically cleared, even though `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` is *not* set and the notification has `Notification.FLAG_NO_CANCEL` set. I've tried various combination of flags including `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` but the behaviour stays the same.

I'd expect the notification to become a 'normal' notification, instead of being cancelled... Any ideas on how to fix this? The docs are not clear on this issue at all...

Code to reproduce:

```
private void showHeadsUpNotification()
{
    final Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(this);
    nb.setContentTitle("Foobar");
    nb.setContentText("I am the content text");
    nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    nb.setOngoing(true);
    nb.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    nb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(), 0));

    // Commenting this line 'fixes' it by not making it heads-up, but that's
    // not what I want...
    nb.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(0, nb.build());
}
```

**Edit:** I've noticed that when the app posting the notification is in the foreground, the notification becomes a regular one, just like I'd expect it to. Swiping the heads-up notification away (regardless of the current foreground app) also produces a regular notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I've come up with the following solution:

1. Add an extra to the contentIntent, indicating it was launched from the notification.
2. Check for that extra in the launched `Activity`
3. If extra is present, repost the notification, but make sure it does not become a heads-up notification.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("launched_from_notification", false)) {
        showNotification(false);
        getIntent().putExtra("launched_from_notification", false);
    }
}

// If your Activity uses singleTop as launchMode, don't forget this
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}    

private void showNotification(boolean showAsHeadsUp)
{
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("launched_from_notification", true);

    final Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(this);
    nb.setContentTitle("Foobar");
    nb.setContentText("I am the content text");
    nb.setOngoing(true);
    nb.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    nb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    nb.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    // Notifications without sound or vibrate will never be heads-up
    nb.setDefaults(showAsHeadsUp ? Notification.DEFAULT_ALL : 0);

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(0, nb.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I could imagine a simple trick is to say your `contentIntent` to do any action **AND** just send the same notification again which is declared as `PRIORITY_DEFAULT` or something. Of course by using the same **notyId**.

I just had the same problem some days ago... the point is that Google has intended this behaviour, this means that if you want to declare your notification as important with advising `PRIORITY_HIGH` or `MAX` it says that this is an urgent case which needs to be treated immediately. So in this case the user has only the option to dismiss it by swiping left or right (the notification won't appear in the notification drawer) or clicking on the notification itself an starting the `contentIntent` (what would cause the notification to disappear because your intenden action was taken).

It would be new for me if there is a way to avoid this behaviour.

Hope I could help

Comment: I'd actually prefer the notification not to be heads-up at all, but at the same time I wanted to retain `PRIORITY_HIGH`. Since sound and/or vibration are also required for a notification to become heads-up, my approach just disables that for the second notification. That way, its `PRIORITY_HIGH`, but not heads-up.